# Binding enabled property from CheckedListBox.Items - Winforms

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding, .net-3.5

I'm relatively new to winforms programming, coming from ASP.NET and I'm struggling to bind things such as "Enabled" field from checklistbox.items.

For example, I have a:

```
class A
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public bool Enabled {get; set;}
}
```

I then create a list items A and bind to a checkedlistbox.

```
List<A> aList = new List<A>(
    new A{Name="Item1", Enabled=true}, 
    new A{Name="Item2", Enabled=false} );

CheckedListBox.DataSource = aList;
CheckedListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Finally, how do I make items with "Enabled==false" to show as disabled in the checkedlistbox?

Of course, I'll need to do the same with the Checked property but for sake of simplicity I'm not adding it to the example.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot perform this kind of rich databinding with the WinForms CheckedListBox.

You can set the DataSource and then the DisplayMember and ValueMember properties but from there on in you have to do the rest with code (including setting the Enabled and Checked properties)

Set the basic binding as shown below:

```
checkedListBox.DataSource = aList; 
checkedListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
checkedListBox.ValueMember = "Name";
```

From there you will need to iterate over the datasource, setting the individual item properties as needed.

One thing that you might be able to do (I haven't tried this but it should work) is subclass the CheckedListBox and but some custom binding code in the new class.

That might give you a more elegant solution - removing code from the code behind, though depending on your situation might not be worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks David. I suspected it wasn't possible but had high hopes I was wrong as it is in other technologies. 

Guess in the end I'll just use another control such as a grid and display a checkbox to mark it as enabled or not, and maybe change its color for UI enhancement.

Comment: The dataGridView control in WinForms is *great* and will do what you need. Grab a copy of the dataGridView FAQ - great document that will help you find the best way of achieving the desired results.

Comment: Although, on reflection, I don't think you can bind the enabled property of dataGridView rows. Checked you can for sure.